# Quantity display in listview

Tags: android

I have a listview that have two buttons for addition and subtracting the value. The buttons are working fine but the problem is when I scroll the list down, data changes. For ex. first quantity was 0, and after adding becomes 1, scroll makes it display 0 only but have been changed in the database.

```
holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String a = holder.quantity.getText().toString();
            Integer qua = Integer.parseInt(a) + 1;
            String q = qua.toString();
            holder.quantity.setText(q);
            //update in database.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of your Adapter?

Comment: You would have to update dataset which is in List when any value changes.For better understanding please paste code here

Comment: Listview items are recycle when you scroll the list. So, you need to store the value which you need to protect(Save) in your list which you passed to adapter.

Comment: make sure you have declare first getView parameter as final or use setTag method for getting right value of clicked row on Button Click

Comment: @Sanat Shukla, can you please elaborate or give an example for the same.

Comment: @Sakshi Agrawal wait, i will give you an example.

Comment: Can you provide whole adapter ?

Comment: I have done myself. Set the quantity value from the database only.

Comment: Good. You need to just set the updated value to your list which you passed to your adapter.  I have put an example below for your reference. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this is happening is because you aren't storing the information in the model of the view. You probably use some kind of `Adapter` to get the view of the list. That adapter should contain a list of values. So that every item in the list, matches an item in the adapter list. That value should represent the state of the view.

So if you handle the click event, you should not only update the view, but also the model behind it.

Now you're only changing the text on the view, but not the value behind the view. So every time the view is repainted (when it comes in view again, after it was out of view), the original default value is put back.

Answer (score 0):

Use Setter And Getter and try to bind the data in view method

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding one line of code :

```
holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String a = holder.quantity.getText().toString();
                Integer qua = Integer.parseInt(a) + 1;
                String q = qua.toString();
                holder.quantity.setText(q);
                //update in database.
                // In above comment you update the database. Now at this place you need to set the "q" to your list which you passed to adapter
                yourList.get(position).setQuantity(q); // here you can set the updated value to your list which automatically reflect to your listview
            }
        });
```